# How can I add vue-router in package.json laravel?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, laravel-5.3, vue-router, package.json

I use laravel 5.3 and vue.js 2

My package.json like this :

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "accounting": "^0.4.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-14",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.3.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "next-tick": "^1.0.0",
    "pusher-js": "^4.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "vuex": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-echo": "^1.1.4",
    "pusher-js": "^4.0.0",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.0-beta.17",
    "vuejs-paginator": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

I want to add vue-router in package.json

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution might be using NPM or Yarn for this:

`npm install vue-router --save-dev`

`yarn add vue-router --dev`